# Google analytics trackEvent() function isn't working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

There are a million threads here on this and I've been through as many as I can muster and still can't get this working. I'm using GA's new tracking code, like so:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'MYTRACKINGNUMBER', 'agoodman.com.au');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'MYTRACKINGNUMBER']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

</script>
```

On certain button-clicks, I want to track an 'event' in Google Analytics. For instance:

```
$("#freeTrial").on('submit', function(e){
        _gaq.push('_trackEvent', 'Signup', 'Free Trial Signup');
 });
```

However, this isn't working. I missed out on tracking 120 (important) events today alone so I'd really like to find out the best way to do this!

On the page in question I've tried checking `_gaq` in Chrome's console and it returns an array[image: Chrome console]

Not sure how this affects things. When I click this button it becomes:

[image]

Perhaps I should be pushing an array into this array or something? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing the [Universal Analytics (analytics.js) event syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) with that of the [old Google Analytics (ga.js) event syntax](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide).

Try updating your event on your form submit to the new syntax:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Signup', 'Free Trial Signup');
```